# "A foremost" correct usage of this superlative?

Tags: superlative-degree

> Among the antiquities of a great nation, its tombs always hold **a foremost** place.

Since foremost means "first in rank," how can something have *a* foremost place, and not *the* foremost place?

Comment: You might as well say there's something wrong with having ***a leading position***. This is just logic-chopping, not reflective of ordinary language use at all. And ***elative*** isn't part of ordinary English either.

Comment: I tend to agree that "A foremost ..." usually sounds a little sour in my ears.  However, if someone says "One of the foremost ..." then for some reason it's better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may indeed be many 'foremost places'. Consider this crude graphic of a regiment of 800 men on the march:

```
     BACK                                                                       FRONT
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Not one but no less than ten men occupy ***a*** (not ***the***) 'foremost place'.

Comment: Ah, yes. I see now.

Comment: That logic may not apply to the context, though. Unless one sees antiquities as a rank-and-file structure.

Answer (score 1):

> Among the antiquities of a great nation, its tombs always hold a foremost place

Simply means that there is more than one foremost place among a nation's antiquities.

Among the antiquities of a great nation, its tombs always hold a foremost place--but so do its libraries.

There is the foremost place among a nation's antiquities for learning how its supreme rulers were arranged for the afterlife, namely, its tombs.

But there is also the foremost place among a nation's antiquities for collecting cuneiform samples, namely, its libraries.

Or consider:

Among a great nation's modernites, its rapid speed trains always hold a foremost place--but so do its shopping malls and hydroelectric plants.

There are different foremost places among a great nation's modernites.